# WCF service solution not working in my System

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF Service solution hosted in server .I am downloading the solution to local and running the service ,it shows 404 not found when browsing it as http://localhost/help,when browsing as http://localhost/Product.svc?wsdl it is showing the wsdl document properly .the solution works fine if it is downloaded in other Computer .
I think the problem is due to IIS configuration in my system.
Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the `/help` segment to the end of your service url (behind the SVC file): http://localhost/Product.svc/help

Comment: I tried  with /help but its still showing the same error

Comment: So just  to clarify: The problem you're experiencing is that the help page doesn't show up. Correct? The service itself runs correctly on your local machine?

Comment: yes service is running but i can't invoke any method .I tried invoking it with SoapUI but its not working. but in other system the same solution and request is working fine.

Comment: also i am able to run the service only in Release mode with X86 Processor .

Comment: "service is running but i can't invoke any method" hmm... Sounds contrary to me... Well, I think you'll have to provide some more Infos. There seems to be something more general to be incorrect.

Comment: I have written a WCF Services and made it Restful by using [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "")] below Operation Contract in each method.Now this service is running fine and i can invoke any method by SoapUI or Fiddler .The Url for invoking a method is like localhost:4030/Catalogue.svc/MethodName.Even when i am typing localhost:4030/Catalogue.svc/help i can see all methods i.e everything is working fine in the service

Comment: Problem is when i am running the same solution in a different Computer first it is throwing Configuration compatibility error ,after googling i found this is due to Processor Incompatibility so i changed CPU to x86 in Visual Studio but still the issue was there so i tried in release mode instead of Debug and it run successfully saying service added successfully ,but when i am trying to invoke any method or help command it is throwing 400 error.    In both the computer the Service is running in IIS Express .I spent 2 days in that but still didn't got the solution